# Why pinterest X-Ratelimit-Remaining: 0 for endpoints I have not even used?

Tags: c#, api, pinterest

I've developed a Pinterest app using C#.  I'm using no plugin.  I use .Net httpclient to interface the pinterest api.  All works fine! But I've been fighting to get their api to respect their promise based on their documentation that says

> Each app (with a unique app ID) is allowed 1000 calls per endpoint per hour for each unique user token

I'm using Fiddler to monitor and debug and notice the following:

1. I make 1000 successful call to this endpoint /v1/me/following/users/
2. I get the 429 You have exceeded your rate limit. Try again later.
   That's exactly what's expected according to Pinteret API documentation.
3. Then I call a whole different endpoint /v1/pins/
   and still get 429 You have exceeded your rate limit.  Now that's not what the Pinterest API documentation says! Unless I misunderstood the doc.

I tried to run the app in single mode but get the same result as parallel mode which run multiple accounts.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The document does not specify a time frame in which calls should be made but I make each call consecutively waiting for each response. it takes about 15 minutes to make 1000 calls to a single endpoint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the EULA more closely - some services will ratelimit if you make too many requests in too short a timespan, as that could have the same affects as a denial of service attack.

In other words, they might say you can make 1000 requests per hour, but that doesn't mean you can make 1000 requests in the space of 1 second, and then wait an hour before making another 1000 requests in a second.

Instead, what you can do is batch your requests. Break your 1000 requests down into batches of 10 (or 20, or 50, or 100) requests, with an X-second wait between each batch.

At the end of the day though, if you feel that Pinterest isn't abiding with their terms of service (such as through a bug in the API or incorrect documentation), then that is something you will have to take up with them.

Comment: I contacted their developer support and waiting but i'm going to test your suggested options now and update soon!

Comment: thank you for but it's a dead end the last part of your statement is accepted:  They are abiding with their terms!